# SQL Server error : incorrect syntax near ',' in integer

Tags: sql-server, integer

I apologize if this is a dumb question but I'm getting an error message in this line and I don't now why. Can someone help?

```
CREATE TABLE cliente 
(
    cpf INTEGER, 
    nome varchar(60), 
    dtnasc date),
    constraint pk_cliente primary key (cpf INTEGER)
);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: `dtnasc date),` Look closely. Why do you have a closing parenthesis here? And the syntax for declaring a primary key needs a reference to the associated columns **by name** - you can't include the datatype as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table cliente (cpf INTEGER not null, nome varchar(60), dtnasc date);
alter table cliente add constraint pk_cliente primary key(cpf)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry again if this is dumb but I executed it and got this error: Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'cliente'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 6
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: amended. not null constraint on cpf-column

Answer (score 1):

```
create table cliente 
(
    cpf int not null
        constraint pk_cliente primary key, 
    nome varchar(60), 
    dtnasc date
);
```